# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice

Tags: java, spring, maven, keycloak

I'm trying to add the [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/spring-security-adapter.html) to an existing Spring application.

So, I've added the `keycloak-spring-security-adapter` to my `pom.xml` and much more dependencies.

I've finally built the project, but when Spring starts I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:222)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
```

I can't figure why, I've already added the following dependency in my `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any idea? Thanks

I've already tried the following, with no success:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
    <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

PS: This is all my dependencies:

```
<dependencies> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
        <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-hibernate4</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Are you specifically trying to use v2.5.5 of keycloak-spring-security-adapter? I ask because much more recent versions are available - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-spring-security-adapter If that wasn't intentional then I'd suggest taking out everything you added to the pom.xml and just adding the version of the adapter that you want. Perhaps you can align your spring security and keycloak versions https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/4.4.0.Final/adapters/oidc/spring-security/pom.xml#L34

Comment: Which version of Spring (`${spring.version}`) are you using?

Comment: The Spring version is 3.1.2.RELEASE, thanks.